# What does "screws" mean here?

Tags: meaning

In submarine, Davis says to Torpedo Room chief:

> DAVIS: The **screws** are fading. I think they're leaving, sir.
>
> Room chief: Take us to periscope depth. Enemy destroyer's headed back
>   to her fleet.

What does "screws" mean here?
I found this line in Midway 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some wider context would help, but in Navy terminology, the propellor on a submarine is called the "screw". They are somewhat different from the propellor on a ship.

As your quote talks about periscope depth and enemies leaving, I would guess they are talking about submarines, and "the screws are fading" likely means that the enemy submarines are disappearing from view into the depths of the ocean.

Comment: Guessing here as well, but I would have thought it was the sounds of the screws fading on sonar, rather than from view.

Comment: The speakers are in a submarine. ('Torpedo room chief', 'take us up', 'periscope depth'). What is fading is the sound of the screws of a destroyer (a surface vessel) which is 'heading back to her fleet'.